# How to combine multiple rows in spark dataframe into single row having the same id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple rows(with same id) of data in spark scala dataframe. how to combine the data for all the rows into single row.

Below screenshot consists of input data and expected data

[image: Dataframe with multiple rows]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362983/merge-rows-in-apache-spark-by-eliminating-null-values) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a `Window` function and then aggregating with [`pyspark.sql.functions.first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html) but ignoring the nulls with `ignorenulls=True` instead of the default `ignorenulls=False`. Finally, take a `.distinct()` to get rid of the duplicate rows (3 each in this case) as the aggregation happens for every row.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("eid")
cols = df.columns
df = (df.select(*[(F.first(col, ignorenulls=True).over(window_spec)).alias(col) for col in cols])
     .distinct()
     )

df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+-----+----+-------+-----+-----------+--------+
|eid|ename|esal|  eaddr|edept|designation|isactive|
+---+-----+----+-------+-----+-----------+--------+
|123|  abc|1000|newyork|   IT|    manager|       y|
|456|  def|2000|chicago| mech|       lead|       n|
+---+-----+----+-------+-----+-----------+--------+
```